# Change From address MAPI

Tags: mapi

I am using MAPI for opening default email client from my C# application, as similar way in this example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SendTo.aspx?df=100&forumid=257922&select=1801097#xx1801097xx

But, is there anyway to define/change from address ?

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses IntPtr for the originator param, which is really a MapiRecipDesc.  Define the managed version of that strucutre (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296720(VS.85).aspx), then set ulRecipClass to MAPI_ORIG, and name and address accordingly.  If you know the entryId of the 'from'address you want to use, set those also.